# Open network folder using FolderDialog by impersonating in c#

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation

I am using following code to impersonate as third user and trying to access folder.

```
Boolean success = LogonUser("username", "domain", "password", 2, 0, out userToken);

if (success)
{
     var wi = new WindowsIdentity(userToken, "WindowsAuthentication");
    using (wi.Impersonate())
      {
         if (fbdPatches.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
                 // try to access folder which can be accessed only through above credentials
         }
      }
}
```

Still I am not able to access folder. Please help me to find out I am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: I got following error.
"Unable to retrieve the root folder"

Actually I am trying to set folderBrowseDialog (fbdPatches) root folder
fbdPatches.SelectedPath = "SomeFolder";

Comment: did you tried with `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS 9` ?

Comment: You can edit your question and add more information: `I got following error. "Unable to retrieve the root folder" Actually I am trying to set folderBrowseDialog (fbdPatches) root folder fbdPatches.SelectedPath = "SomeFolder"`

Answer (score 0):

**LogonUser** takes a user name, domain, and password, and returns us a token that we can use with WindowsIdentity.  In addition to these parameters, LogonUser wants to know which logon provider to use (the default should suffice for most cases), and a logon type  Selecting a logon type can be a tricky, so the Options are

**Logon Type (LOGON32_LOGON_xxx)**  **Integer Value(From WinBase.h)**

LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH                  **4**

LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE            **2**

LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK                **3**

LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT      **8**

LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS        **9**

LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE                **5**

Your problem is solved by using NEW_CREDENTIALS option for logon.

**For example:**

```
Boolean success = LogonUser("username", "domain", "password", 9, 0, out userToken);
```

or

```
Boolean success = LogonUser("username", "domain", "password", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, 0, out userToken);
```